# Error installing pointnet2_ops_lib: "RuntimeError: The detected CUDA version (11.8) mismatches the version that was used to compile PyTorch (11.7)."

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm replicating the point cloud model from https://github.com/ZrrSkywalker/Point-NN/tree/main using Python 3.7.

When I run:

```
pip install pointnet2_ops_lib/.
```

I get the following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.nju.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
Processing ./pointnet2_ops_lib
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.4 in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99 in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96 in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (8.5.0.96)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66 in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (11.10.3.66)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99 in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch>=1.4->pointnet2-ops==3.0.0) (0.41.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pointnet2-ops
  Building wheel for pointnet2-ops (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [91 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops
      copying pointnet2_ops/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops
      copying pointnet2_ops/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops
      copying pointnet2_ops/pointnet2_modules.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops
      copying pointnet2_ops/pointnet2_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops
      running egg_info
      writing pointnet2_ops.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pointnet2_ops.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pointnet2_ops.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pointnet2_ops.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pointnet2_ops.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'pointnet2_ops.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/ball_query.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/cuda_utils.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/group_points.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/interpolate.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/sampling.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include/utils.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/include
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/ball_query.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/ball_query_gpu.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/bindings.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/group_points.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/group_points_gpu.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/interpolate.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/interpolate_gpu.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/sampling.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      copying pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src/sampling_gpu.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pointnet2_ops/_ext-src/src
      running build_ext
      /home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:365: UserWarning:

                                     !! WARNING !!

      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      Your compiler (g++ 4.8.5) may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch!
      Please use a compiler that is ABI-compatible with GCC 5.0 and above.
      See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html.

      See https://gist.github.com/goldsborough/d466f43e8ffc948ff92de7486c5216d6
      for instructions on how to install GCC 5 or higher.
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                                    !! WARNING !!

        warnings.warn(ABI_INCOMPATIBILITY_WARNING.format(compiler))
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/home/3DVision2021/yifeiwang/Point-NN/pointnet2_ops_lib/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
          include_package_data=True,
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 87, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 499, in build_extensions
          _check_cuda_version(compiler_name, compiler_version)
        File "/home/3DVision2021/.conda/envs/pointnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 386, in _check_cuda_version
          raise RuntimeError(CUDA_MISMATCH_MESSAGE.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda))
      RuntimeError:
      The detected CUDA version (11.8) mismatches the version that was used to compile
      PyTorch (11.7). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pointnet2-ops
  Running setup.py clean for pointnet2-ops
Failed to build pointnet2-ops
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pointnet2-ops, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install nes-py --no-cache-dir
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

but it doesn't fix the error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I have edited the content and put the complete error information

Comment: Now the error is more clear, your actual error seems to be about **"_RuntimeError: The detected CUDA version (11.8) mismatches the version that was used to compile PyTorch (11.7). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions._"** There's also a warning about your g++ compiler. Do not focus on "*could not build wheels ... which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects*" because that's just the template error message on most (if not all) pip install errors. Focus instead the CUDA error. I'm not familiar with the libraries you are using though.

Comment: I suggest checking your conda env, and what got installed with the command `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit` (as mentioned in the Github page). CHeck that you have the compatible versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after I installed the corresponding version of torch and updated gcc, it does install correctly!

Comment: Nice, @yWang. Consider posting an answer showing the steps you did to fix it as well as the versions you have installed. Might be helpful for others encountering the same problem and/or using the same library.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following these steps：

1. From the error found that the environment is not compiled, it is presumed that the environment may lack pytorch-cuda package, install the corresponding package:

   ```
   pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
   ```
2. After the package is installed, it is found that it can be compiled, but an error message is displayed:

   Your compiler (g++ 4.8.5) may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch!
   Please use a compiler that is ABI-compatible with GCC 5.0 and above.
   See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html.
   See https://gist.github.com/goldsborough/d466f43e8ffc948ff92de7486c5216d6
   for instructions on how to install GCC 5 or higher.

   The core error is 'You're running a too old version of GCC. We need GCC 5 or later'.Install more than 5 versions of GCC (after verification, there appear to be only 5 versions applicable).Find the appropriate package installation at https://anaconda.org/.
   For example:

   ```
   conda install -c psi4 gcc-5-mp
   ```

pointnet2_ops_lib/ can then be successfully installed.

Comment: I tried following the same steps on my machine (I have a nvidia 4090)... when I run the command "conda install -c psi4 gcc-5-mp", i get the error - UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35

Comment: I haven't encountered this error, but the version of glibc required by the package doesn't seem to match the version of glibc you currently have installed. Maybe try getting the latest version of glibc.